hashicorp vault oidc keycloak via squid proxy
Is there a way how to configure that Hashicorp vault connects to keycloak oidc via squid proxy? How can I achieve that ?
I tried to connect from vault to keycloak oidc directly but the connection is blocked by fw, so we need to use squid proxy in between.

squid was a system used in a large car manufacturer to analyse concerns data - what are you doing with it?
